Stripe: A way to make subscription upgrades/downgrade happen at the end of the billing cycle? (using customer portal)
I do not understand how to handle the UI part of subscription upgrades/downgrades that should start at the end of the current billing cycle.
The only built in "stripe hosted" page that handles subscription upgrades/downgrades is the customer billing portal. But, from what I understand, there is no option in the billing portal to make the subscription upgrades only take place at the end of the current subscription's billing cycle.
There is the subscription scheduling API, which makes sense to use. Thing is, I want to use the interface of the customer portal, and have the functionality that a subscription scheduling would have. A strategy, that does not seem sound to me, that I have thought of is the following:

Let the user use the billing portal to change their subscription.
Stripe instantly updates the subscription on their end.
When the webhook reaches my server I tell stripe to revert the changes it made, and schedule a subscription for next month.

Is this the only way, or a right way at all, to handle this use case?

Yes, it's not possible to schedule updates via Customer Portal out-of-the-box.
Subscription Schedules would be ideal for that, but you will need to build your own interface for customers to use. This is the right way to solve this.
You could potentially try the strategy you suggested, but you might run into edge cases where customers are double-charged, and you will need to deal with refunds etc. For example, when you reset the billing cycle (monthly <-> yearly) and they are charged immediately. I would not recommend it.

That's weird to me.. I think a customer would be skeptical managing their plans from an UI page made by me, when the rest of the payments are made through stripe hosted pages.
